# pgadmin4 upload file option is not understand below picture is for your reference

Tags: pgadmin-4

[Could you Please let me know what is this option in PgAdmin4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldWNx.png)

Answer (score 0):

This option is useful when you run pgAdmin4 in SERVER mode where your `DATA_DIR` directory is on remote web server and you want to import some file for example a CSV file from your local system into your table, Web server can not access your local system files directly so first you have to upload that CSV file on that web server and then you can import that CSV file into your table.

Hope this will be useful.